# Inherit from Eigen Matrix and construct or map from memory

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, eigen

I'm running few test with eigen (as replacement of the boost matrix I'm currently use) and as I tried to define **CTOR** for **a class on top the Eigen Matrix** I meet an issue with a piece of code that create a lot of noisy **warning**. The issue is clearly coming from a confusion on the **Template Type** between scalar type and pointer on a scalar Type.

all help or advice will be welcome,
thanks.

I define the following template class

```
template<typename T>
 class CVector : public Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, 1, Eigen::StorageOptions::AutoAlign>
 {
  public:
   typedef typename Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, 1, Eigen::StorageOptions::AutoAlign> Base_Vector;
   .....
```

I use the piece of code provided by the Eigen doc to construct from Eigen object and few line below 3 constructors

```
CVector(size_t size1) : Base_Vector(size1)
{}
CVector(size_t size1, T val): Base_Vector(size1)
{
    this->setConstant(5);
}
CVector(T* val_array, size_t val_array_size): Base_Vector(val_array_size)
{
    std::copy(val_array, val_array+val_array_size, this->data());
}
```

But the last CTOR lead to a lot of waring as soon as I try to use it by writing something like:

```
   int tab [] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
   CVector<int> v3(tab, 5);
```

From VS'2015 I get:

```
warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'const int', possible loss of data
note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Eigen::internal::is_convertible_impl<unsigned __int64,int>' being compiled
note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Eigen::internal::is_convertible<std::T,int>' being compiled
with
[
    T=std::size_t
]
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'Eigen::Matrix<int,-1,1,0,-1,1>::Matrix<std::size_t>(const T &)' being compiled
with
[
    T=std::size_t
]
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'Eigen::Matrix<int,-1,1,0,-1,1>::Matrix<std::size_t>(const T &)' being compiled
with
[
    T=std::size_t
]
note: while compiling class template member function 'CVector<int>::CVector(T *,std::size_t)'
with
[
    T=int
]
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'CVector<int>::CVector(T *,std::size_t)' being compiled
with
[
    T=int
]
note: see reference to class template instantiation 'CVector<int>' being compiled
```

But on another side, no warning at all when I use

```
float tab [] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
CVector<float> v3(tab, 5);
```

Comment: How `Eigen::Matrix` constructor looks like? Probably its `argument` member variable specialized with `int` type, but you pass the `size_t` to the constructor - conversion between these two produces the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eigen uses a signed type to store sizes and for indexing. This type is `Eigen::Index` which by default is a typedef for `std::ptr_diff`. Just replace your `size_t` by `Eigen::Index` and while your are doing that, you can also replace your constructor implementations by these:

```
CVector(Eigen::Index size1) : Base_Vector(size1) {}
CVector(Eigen::Index size1, T val)
    : Base_Vector(Base_Vector::Constant(size1, val) { }
CVector(T const * val_array, Eigen::Index val_array_size)
    : Base_Vector(Base_Vector::Map(val_array, val_array_size) { }
```

Btw: No idea, why `CVector<float> v3(tab, 5);` did not raise the same warning as the `int` variant ...